# How to see media files (namely `flv`) details/info in Windows 7?

Tags: media, bitrate

I see that for many media files, under Properties/Details there are some needed info like audio/video bitrate, but it seems limited - for example it does not work for flv.

Is there a way that would extend this possibility?

---

I was trying to convert some files to mp3, and in order to do that properly i have to know what is the input bitrate in order to set the same for output

I am aware that superuser discourages asking for a specific program: I am not asking for that, but for a generic answer - what to do about it in general.

---

I had a comment saying:

(i) there is no such ONE tool for all media files;

(but i see that win7 already does that except for flv. why?)

(ii) that i need a tool that 'supports' flv.

(what does that mean? i already can convert and play the flv but know nothing about the audio bitrate)

Comment: We don't really do software product recomendations on Superuser.  there isn't a single tool that does this or covers ever single media type.  You just have to search for a specific tool that supports `.flv` files

Comment: @Ramhound - i was trying to convert some files to mp3, and in order to do that properly i have to know what is the input bitrate in order to set the same for output - more [here](http://superuser.com/q/593869/162573). no tool for all media? in linux there are a lot of tools that can display info of many if not "all" media formats (like [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/286626/47206)). why not in windows? considering "support"": you mean a converter or a player? i can play and convert the flv but the player/converter doesn't tell me much about it.

Comment: @Ramhound: have edited the question to comply

Comment: Have you tried MediaInfo?...wont put stuff in "prpperties" but will get you all the details...

Comment: @cipricus - It seems in today's age there are more video codecs and file containers then people in the world.  Microsoft can only write native support for so many.  Just find a video player that supports the codec and .flv container and it should provide this information to you.

Comment: @tumchaaditya - if you want to provide an answer please do. i could then delete mine or edit yours to add what's in mine

Comment: @cipricus:done..

Comment: @Ramhound: "Microsoft can only write native support for so many." Not just that, codecs are a ***massive*** patent minefield (see for example what happened when they were trying to decide what codecs to support in HTML5). So MS *cannot* provide codec support for free and would need to most likely pass on the costs to *all* end users, which obviously is not an option (that's why they removed DVD support in Win8). Also, if they did try to do so I'm pretty sure the EU or some other body would slap them down once more based on someone's complaint about monopolistic practices etc.

Comment: @Karan - Let alone the fact they now have to pay Motroloa like 0.05 for every Windows license and a similar amount for every Xbox for one particular video codec.  You of course make a good point, for every codec they write native support for, they have to actually provide support for it and pay any costs connected to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en)

It is a freeware and puts a right-click context menu item so that you can quickly get info about most of the media files.

[image]

---

Also as an addition, try Free Studio: http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/free-dvd-video-software.htm
It has a host of media conversion tools including dedicated tools for flash(flv) videos. If I remember correctly, these flv converters allow you to keep the bitrate same while conversion so you don't have to bother checking bitrate for each file.

Comment: i see that you gave me a supplementary answer to [my other question](http://superuser.com/q/593869/162573). i am used with [Format Factory](http://www.pcfreetime.com/), but am always curious to find new and better

Comment: but Free Studio is not better, not at all (and contains some adware)